# Transducer on core.async channels

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

If i have 10 buffered subscription channels each with a transducer that takes 5sec to execute. Are the transducers going to be executed concurrent or all on the same thread (assuming multithreaded context)?

Comment: Couldn't both be true? With task switching in ClojureScript there is one thread yet they are all executing concurrently.

Comment: It is really up to core.async what it does. You could read up on the guarantees. But I know for sure that if you match the number of channels you have to the number of cores on your computer and nothing else is running you can get maximum CPU usage on all cores at once. That tells me that real threads (not virtual threads) are being used, one by each channel, which is what you would expect core.async to try to do on a Java execution environment. I don't think that the word 'transducer' is that relevant to the question however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is quite easy to check, logging the thread, the transducer is being executed by:

```
(def log-chan (chan))

(go-loop []
  (println (<! log-chan))
  (recur))

(def channels
  (repeatedly
    10
    #(chan 10
       (map (fn [item]
              (let [thread (Thread/currentThread)]
                (go (>! log-chan thread)))
              item)))))

(doseq [c channels]
  (go (>! c :item)))
```

output:

```
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x77a39fa0 Thread[async-dispatch-27,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x7d5bf4d0 Thread[async-dispatch-31,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x53ecb32b Thread[async-dispatch-29,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x2b74f3ac Thread[async-dispatch-25,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x6eb50f9e Thread[async-dispatch-26,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x30701edb Thread[async-dispatch-30,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x1a370b69 Thread[async-dispatch-36,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x3d9884a2 Thread[async-dispatch-24,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x208941d0 Thread[async-dispatch-23,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x2c77aeb Thread[async-dispatch-28,5,main]]
```

so you can see, there are different threads.

But it really depends on a `go` block, inside which you send data to your channel, so if you change this:

```
(doseq [c channels]
  (go (>! c :item)))
```

to this:

```
(go (doseq [c channels]
  (>! c :item)))
```

you get this output:

```
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
#object[java.lang.Thread 0x16856295 Thread[async-dispatch-6,5,main]]
```

so all channels' transducers would use the same thread

Answer (score 1):

They will be executed in parallel, so on different real threads at the same time. Your machine might not have 10 cores however, so there will be some parking and blocking. You can look up the technical details [here](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/) in the section 'Parking and Blocking'.